# как расположить иконку в центре рамки?

Tags: html

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.fa {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border: 6px solid white;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  display: inline-block;;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<i class="fa fa-facebook" style="font-size: 30px;"></i>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Иконка добавляется через `::before`, от центрируйте его, простой способ это `position: absolute`

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.fa {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border: 6px solid white;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.fa::before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<i class="fa fa-facebook" style="font-size: 30px;"></i>
```

Либо через `display: flex` (`inline-flex`)

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');

body {
  background: black;
}

.fa {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border: 6px solid white;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<i class="fa fa-facebook" style="font-size: 30px;"></i>
```